# Weights for TableLayout and LinearLayout are not the same

Tags: android, android-layout, android-linearlayout, android-tablelayout

Why do not the TableLayout and LinearLayout weights mean the same? Or do I have an error in the layout XMLs?

**4 button test**

I've prepared a simple test with 4 buttons having weights 1,1,1,3. The result is not the same using TableLayout (one column) and LinearLayout (vertical).

On the following link you can see a screenshot of both TableLayout (left) and LinearLayout (right) implementation.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/9dYlB.png

In my opinion the LinearLayout is correct - sum is 6, so the fourth button with weight 3 should be taking half the space.

**TableLayout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="A" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="B" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="C" />
    </TableRow>
    <TableRow
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3" >
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="D" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

**LinearLayout XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="A" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="B" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="C" />
    <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:text="D" />
</LinearLayout>
```

**Environment**

ADT: 22.6.2
AVD: Intel Atom with 4.2.2 and 4.4.2 (both the same result)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that if you change your weight value of the final button to 7 you'll achieve the same result as your second xml file. I think this is because it's accounting for the extra weight values you've put in the file by attributing both the tablerows and the buttons with weight. Here's what I used:

Edit: to be more clear, you have a weightsum (total) of 14 with this edited version, the final button has 7, which is half of the total. In your button-only layout you have a different weightsum.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="A" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="B" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="C" />
</TableRow>
<TableRow
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="7" >
    <Button
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:text="D" />
</TableRow>
```

Comment: You're right. All the weights sums up, TableRow and Button ones. The Button weights were redundant anyway, as I've tested. Thank you.